# ternary multiple conditions with multiple values

Tags: php, ternary-operator

Trying to return the value of either $dy or $days.  Sometimes $dy is set, other times $days is set.

For example: $dy['value'] = 45 or $days['value'] = 75
(only one value will be set)

However when I execute this statement the value is always equal to 1.
How can I return the actual value of either $dy or $days.

```
$days = isset($dy['value']) || isset($days['value']) ? ($dy['value'] || $days['value']) : null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `1`:

In PHP, `||` doesn't do what you might expect coming from JavaScript, because the result will always be a boolean. `||` implicitely converts its operands to booleans and returns the result.

To get the equivalent of a short-circuit `||` from JavaScript in PHP, you can use `?:` (the so-called "Elvis operator" - `x ?: y` is a shorthand for `x ? x : y`):

```
$days = isset($dy['value']) || isset($days['value']) ? ($dy['value'] ?: $days['value']) : null;
```

I didn't change the first `||` because it's indeed a boolean operation, but I did replace the second.

---

However I think there is a logic error in your code anyway, because if you have `E_NOTICE` error reporting on, PHP will complain anyway if `$days['value']` is set and `$dy['value']` isn't, because you are still accessing `$dy['value']` even if `isset($dy['value']) == false`. So you would need to use, for example:

```
$days = (isset($dy['value']) ? $dy['value'] : null) ?: (isset($days['value']) ? $days['value'] : null);
```

(Assuming you also want to skip a value if it's falsy - according to how you are using the `||` it looks like it.)

If you don't care about notice errors at all (discouraged!) you could just use:

```
$days = $dy['value'] ?: $days['value'] ?: null;
```

Comment: Thx! Added explanation about what this operator actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you need a ternary? In this case an if elseif would probably be cleaner and easier to read.

```
if ( isset($dy['value']) )
{
    $days = $dy['value'];
} elseif ( isset($days['value'] )
{
    $days = $days['value'];
}
```

If it absolutely must be a ternary, you need a ternary within a ternary:

```
$days = isset($dy['value']) ? $dy['value'] : (
            isset($days['value']) ? $days['value'] : null
        );
```

If you're using PHP 5.3+ (which you should be) this should work to:

```
$days = $dy['value'] ?: ( $days['value'] ?: null );
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess This might be what you wanted:

```
$days = (isset($dy['value']) || isset($days['value'])) ? (isset($dy['value'])?$dy['value'] : $days['value'])) : null;
```